# I would like to update DENSE_RANK for a table whenever a new row is inserted or updated or commited

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

Table 1 :

| ID | Action Performed Indicator | Event Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | text 1 | 2023-03-31 10:00:00 |
| 1001 | text 2 | 2023-03-31 10:00:00 |
| 1001 | text 1 | 2023-03-28 10:50:00 |

I would like to update dense rank in same table every time whenever a new row is inserted or updated or committed. I'm ok to use trigger or stored procedures ( no '**$'** or '**@'** or '**:'** can be used as it is for MYSQL)

Base query used:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY 'ID', 'Action Performed Indicator' 
                   ORDER BY 'Event Time' DESC)
```

I have these issues:

1. Window function usage not allowed
2. Can't use explicit or implicit command
3. Could not able to use update query in stored function

My result should be:

| ID | Action Performed Indicator | Event Time | ranker |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | text 1 | 2023-03-31 10:00:00 | 1 |
| 1001 | text 2 | 2023-03-31 10:00:00 | 1 |
| 1001 | text 1 | 2023-03-28 10:50:00 | 2 |

Comment: You would probably be better off generating the rank in `SELECT`, and not have a column.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest *not* doing this update, primarily because any time your data changes you would be forced to run the update again.  Instead, I suggest just doing the select directly:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, `Action Performed Indicator`, `Event Time`,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, `Action Performed Indicator`
                              ORDER BY `Event Time` DESC) AS ranker
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ID, `Action Peformed Indicator`, `Event Time`
FROM cte
WHERE ranker = 1;
```

The above query should benefit from the following index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (ID, `Action Performed Indicator`, `Event Time` DESC);
```

The above index should allow for rapid evaluation of the `DENSE_RANK()` function.

Comment: We have a 2 systems here , one is reporting system which is synced to SQL server. In  Reporting system , query writing facilities will not be there. So only way is update and trigger. . As a admin I will write this trigger in server directly , so that others can use reporting system.. Can you suggest for the same

Comment: @SRIHARIVENKATESAN Your plan is to keep a separate reporting system up to date _row by row_? This will not scale. I suggest looking into a variety of other methods to provide near-real-time or not real-time copies for reporting purposes.